# How to unit test System.Windows.Application.Run()?

Tags: c#, wpf, unit-testing

I am trying to write a unit test for the following method:

```
public override void Run()
{
    base.Run();
    this.wpfApplication.Run();
}
```

Note that "this.wpfApplication" is an instance of System.Windows.Application.

I am using Microsoft's Test Explorer to run my tests (in VS Express 2013).

If I run the unit test it will hang on the .Run() line.

How can I create a unit test to run this method?

I already have a unit test to test the base class's implementation of the Run method.  The base class is part of a framework which supports console and WPF apps.

Comment: What is your test trying to assert?

Comment: Unit tests prove some fact is true about your code, tell us what fact are you attempting to prove and that will help us show you what you would need to do.

Comment: In `base.Run` I can Assert that an ApplicationStartDateTime property is not null.  This proves that the Run method had been executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with almost all other cases where I call a .NET class method, I ended up writing an interface (e.g. `IWpfRun`) and used a mock implementation in my unit tests.  It does mean that I need to do more in my constructors (as I need to specify which implementation to use).

Now my unit tests are concerned with **my methods** rather than mixing in concerns of .NET class methods such as running a WPF app, logging to a file etc.

My `IWpfRun` interface has 2 implementations.  One is my `WpfRun` class that wraps the `System.Windows.Application.Run` method in override of my interface's `Run` method.  The second implementation is my `WpfRunMock` class, that overrides the same method with an update of a property.  I can assert the property value has been updated after the `Run` method has been called.

Comment: If you need `System.Windows.Application.Run()` for unit testing then you are probably doing it wrong. Say you have a startup View, which has related ViewModel, then it's the VM that should set the time stamp and that'd be the "unit" you want to test.